# How to make an Android widget

Tags: android-widget

Added a widget to a project and edited the result to show a simple counter -- or so I thought.

```
class TestWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("TestWidget", 0)
        val n:Int = prefs.getInt("n", 1)
        val e = prefs.edit()
            e.putInt("n", n + 1)
        e.apply()
        e.commit()

        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, n)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int,
    value:Int
) {
    val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.test_widget)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, value.toString())

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

In `test_widget_info.xml` I changed `updatePeriodMillis` to `500`.

I can add the widget to the home screen, but neither `updateAppWidget` nor `onUpdate` are never called.

However *something* must update the widget because the `TextView` has its text set to `EXAMPLE` but when running it is changed to *Problem loading widget*.

Is it possible to make this work? Is it possible to make a widget? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It can't update more than once every 30 minutes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis

Workarounds suggest either a `Service` or a `Timer`, but do not explain how.